# What is the limit of function $\frac{z}{\bar{z}-z}$ at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Just want to check. What is the limit of function $\frac{z}{\bar{z}-z}$ at $z=0$? 
I got $\lim_{\substack{z \to 0 \\ z \in \mathbb{R}}} \frac{z}{\overline{z}-z} =-\infty$

and $\lim_{\substack{z \to 0 \\ z \in i\mathbb{R}}} \frac{z}{\overline{z}-z} =-\frac{1}{2}$, so $f$ is not defined at $z=0$?
Byt the way does this have any singularities? And finally is this analytic in unit circle?

Comment: This function is undefined on the whole real line. Hence, the limit does not exist

Comment: Consequently, it cannot be analytic in the unit circle.

Comment: @MTurgeon: How to show that it is undefined on the whole real line? Just hint.

Comment: @alvoutila what is $\bar z - z$ when $z$ is real?

Comment: @MTurgeon: Now I got it. $\bar{z}-z=x-iy-x-iy=-i2y=0$, when $z$ is real. So regardless of $z$ $\frac{z}{\bar{z}-z} = \infty$?

Comment: @alvoutila You cannot divide by zero; your function is simply undefined on the real line (in particular, it is not equal to $\infty$).

Comment: So I guess because limit does not exist, $f$ is not continuous at $z=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to see that the limit of $f(z) = \frac{z}{\bar z - z}$ as $z\to0$ depends on the direction of approach. For that we write $z = r e^{i\theta}$. Then
$$f(z) = \frac{r e^{i\theta}}{r e^{-i\theta} -r e^{i \theta}} = \frac{1}{e^{-2i\theta} -1}$$
and the value of $f(z)$ depends on the angle $\theta$ but not on $r$.

Comment: ...which means that the limit is not well defined.

Answer (score 0):

Change to polar coordinates $z=r {\rm e}^{i \theta} $ and notice that your function depends only on $\theta.$ This tells you that the limit does not exist.